# Strange styles applied on button

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am making component button with image inside.
I removed borders of button, but there is strange line under the image, that can not been seen in inspector? Any clues?

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

Comment: That strange line depends on background color...

Comment: Can you add a code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to fix it:
Make button `display: inline-flex;` or better make image `display: block;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image

Answer (score 1):

that is because height of your button is 53px and height of image is 50px so u see a line which is a 3px leftover.
give your image a height of 53px

Comment: I can read... I know that button height is 53...
I am asking why button height is 53?! And how to make button take content height...